# Is there a way to ro run a init php code when a page is requested?

Tags: codeigniter, initialization

I am very new in CodeIgniter, what i am looking for is to run a php code when each time a user load the site.

i want to do some security checks (user logged?load session parameters....)

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you want to do, a hook may be suitable. It will allow you to run code for every request at a certain point:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: great links, thanks a lot. but the link to download the library is broken http://codeigniter.com/wiki/File:filters_hook_v2.1b.zip

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link before (edited now), you don't actually need the filters_hook library. ["Hooks"](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) are built into codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [Phil Sturgeon's post on Keeping It Dry](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY). He explains how you should develop your controllers such that they inherit from a base controller that manages the user access/logins/sessions and even administrative functionality in the `__construct();` function.

Comment: interesting, i will consider it